# Implement SSL in website

Tags: php, linux, https

Our company have purchased SSL certificate and installed in linux on Host Server.
Can you plz tell me how to make use of this in our website. How to configure it in Website.Is there any need to write code in our Website pages?
Any suggestion ? Help me out...

Comment: You need check out oficial site of your WWW server (nginx, apache, iis etc) how to install it on server. In your server-side php is nothing change only rewrite http to https

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the answer you expect, but actually it's just a matter of calling a page with HTTPS `https://www.example.com` instead of HTTP. The easiest way to organize links between your pages is, to use only relative links on your pages (not including the protocoll http://), so if you follow a link or post a form, the request will inherit the protocoll.

The biggest problem will be, that you should *ensure*, that pages are requested exclusively with HTTPS, and redirect all other requests (somebody could call your page manually with HTTP). This can be done in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write any extra code in website / webpages  . and you need to install Intermediate CA Certificate along with SSL e ( in case of Thawte - it is available on the THAWTE website ) you need to bind this encrypted data with the ssl certificate .

to know more about CA Certificate you can check this links [THAWTE CA Certificates](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=AR1384)
 [Information about CA certificates](http://manage.logicboxes.com/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq1163.html)r . if you are using c panel it is very easy . there is no need to write any code in the website but you must install this certificate on the serve
 . i am not sure about your SSL provider but still it could help you .

---